# Cannot insert NULL value into the primary key column error

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, insert

We have developed an ASP.NET application and the pen testing reported the following error

> Improper error handling is observed in the application.The application
>   discloses database details such as table name and column name during
>   SQL query execution. This vulnerability is identified when the
>   parameter “txtCity” is left blank and the form is submitted.

The database details are disclosed in the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column ‘column_name’, table
>   ‘table_name’; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement
>   has been terminated."

The sql statement is executed as a stored procedure . We are unable to replicate the error on the web page however we try and submit the form. Please help us resolve the issue. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to submit the form without providing city? You can mess with the submitted values using Fiddler for example to simply not submit anything for `txtCity` or disable javascript if  client side validation prevents you reproducing this. Also turn custom errors on in the web.config so that the error message is not displayed.

Comment: Can you show us the table structure, proc, and the code?

Answer (score 1):

A penetration tester will simply be looking at how your form is submitted, then re-submitting it manually, ignoring any validation you have in the front-end.

This can be done in any number of ways. For example, monitoring the requests between a browser and your site using something like the [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/) Proxy, or even simple inspection in a browser's developer tools, will show where your form submission endpoint is, the parameters it takes and the submission method used. Then an attacker can just send whatever data they want to your form endpoint, using whatever tools they have.

The point is that *all* front-end security provided by a web page can be quite easily bypassed in order to send any parameter values whatever to a form submission page. So you must consider your back-end security. Don't rely on "security" in a web page's front-end code; front-end validation code is just there to give a helping hand to a legitimate user.

You could solve your general case by stopping SQL errors being displayed to the front-end, or in this particular case you could ensure in your server code that all your form parameters are valid before trying to execute SQL queries on your database based on those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

User Custom Error of the web config file as follow

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Templates/PageNotFound.html" />
         ...
         ...
    </customErrors>
 <system.web>
```

Then there will not be any custom error will not be shown.
Also you can use Gloabal file to keep track of your error occurred in your application.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Validate the text box before input **txtCity** from java-script as well as your code-behind.
The reason may be **java-script disabled** by the testing team. So your java-script validation is not working.
So validate the text from the C# or vb which ever you are using.